# Why some directories i can't drag and drop on listBox1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is a path of a folder with images inside i'm trying to drag and drop into the listBox1:

C:\Users\chocolade1972\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\images

But if i drag a folder in c:\ for example c:\images then it will be drag fine into the listBox1.

When i drag the User...directory i see this black symbol that i can't drop it in.

```
private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
                label6.Text = files.Length.ToString();
                filesCount = files.Length-1;
                beginConvertionToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(files[i]);
                  if (listBox1.Items.Contains(fi.FullName))
                  {

                  }
                  else
                  {
                      string directoryName = fi.DirectoryName;
                      string[] filesExtension = Directory.GetFiles(directoryName).Select(p => Path.GetExtension(p)).Distinct().OrderBy(p => p).ToArray();
                      for (int d = 0; d < filesExtension.Length; d++)
                      {
                          if (fi.Extension.ToLower() == filesExtension[d])
                          {
                              listBox1.Items.Add(fi.FullName);
                          }
                      }

                  }
                }
                this.Select();
            }
        }
```

And the drag over event:

```
private void listBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

                bool bfound = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(files[i]);
                    string directoryName = fi.DirectoryName;
                    string[] filesExtension = Directory.GetFiles(directoryName).Select(p => Path.GetExtension(p)).Distinct().OrderBy(p => p).ToArray();
                    for (int d = 0; d < filesExtension.Length; d++)
                      {
                          if (fi.Extension.ToLower() == filesExtension[d])
                        {
                            bfound = true;
                        }
                      }
                }

                if (bfound)
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                else
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
            else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;

        }
```

Comment: first question I would ask is have you checked the permission on that folder..? have you tried to access it manually outside of code..? have you tried running `Visual Studion as Admin`

Comment: DJ KRAZE i tried now all the options you mentioned. If i'm running from visual studio as admin or not admin it didn't change anything. Also if i'm running it from the outside from the hard disk from the debug directory there if it's as admin i can't even drag directories from c:\ and not the User....And if it's not admin i can drag and drop directories from c:\ and not from the User....

Comment: I would suggest doing a google search on `Drag and Drop Directory's to ListBox` here is one that came up in a search I just did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189779/drag-and-drop-a-folder-from-windows-explorer-to-listbox-in-c-sharp